# SFML seconds counter

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm making a game using SFML Library, I wanna implement a function showing the seconds on the screen since the running of the program, and it will get increasing until the window is closed. I tried this:

```
sf::Clock clock;
while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Time elapsed = clock.restart();
    updateGame(elapsed);

}
```

But I have no idea how it's work or even if it's the right function.
Here is my code so far https://github.com/basmaashouur/GamesLib/blob/master/cards/main.cpp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get the number of seconds.

First of all, you can use an exclusive `sf::Clock` for this that's never reset:

```
sf::Clock clock;

const unsigned int seconds = static_cast<unsigned int>(clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds());
```

As an alternative, you can use an `sf::Time` to accumulate the time between frames (e.g. inside your `updateGame()` function):

```
sf::Clock clock;
sf::Time time;

time += clock.restart();

const unsigned int seconds = static_cast<unsigned int>(time.asSeconds());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I wanna show the seconds on the screen and it will get increasing until the window is closed.

Comment: @BasmaAshour That's basically that. In my example you can convert `seconds` to a string (e.g. `std::to_string(seconds)`) and display that using `sf::Text`.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate your help. I did exactly as you said but there is nothing on the screen and when I tried to cout it, the output was zero. I don't know what is wrong, here is my code: https://github.com/basmaashouur/GamesLib/blob/master/cards/main.cpp

Comment: @BasmaAshour You construct your `sf::Clock` right before using it. `getElapsedTime()` returns the time since the clock's creation; not since the application's start! You should move it outside, e.g. creating it as a class member.